# make clean error, windows

Tags: windows, debugging, makefile

When I run make clean in cmd (using Make for Windows - GnuWin32 and MinGW) I get the following error message:

```
 make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
 make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

I'm pretty sure I've set my `$PATH` variable correctly (GnuWin32/bin and MinGW/bin are both included). Any thoughts on what might be causing this error?

The entire output from the make clean command is included below. It's really long, but there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it other than the error tag, which comes after an attempt to call CreateProcess. I've also included the makefile, it's below the output of the make clean command.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Adam>cd Desktop/pl2015/sf

C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\pl2015\sf>make clean
'{' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
rm -f Symbols.vo Preface.vo Basics.vo Induction.vo Lists.vo Poly.vo MoreCoq.vo L
ogic.vo Prop.vo MoreLogic.vo ProofObjects.vo MoreInd.vo SfLib.vo Rel.vo Imp.vo I
mpParser.vo ImpCEvalFun.vo Extraction.vo Equiv.vo Hoare.vo Hoare2.vo HoareAsLogi
c.vo Smallstep.vo Auto.vo Types.vo Stlc.vo StlcProp.vo MoreStlc.vo Sub.vo Typech
ecking.vo Records.vo References.vo RecordSub.vo Norm.vo LibTactics.vo UseTactics
.vo UseAuto.vo PE.vo Postscript.vo Assignment01.vo Assignment_02.vo Assignment03
.vo Assignment04.vo Assignment05_00.vo Assignment05_01.vo Assignment05_02.vo Ass
ignment05_03.vo Assignment05_04.vo Assignment05_05.vo Assignment05_06.vo Assignm
ent05_07.vo Assignment05_08.vo Assignment05_09.vo Assignment05_10.vo Assignment0
5_11.vo Assignment05_12.vo Assignment05_13.vo Assignment05_14.vo Assignment05_15
.vo Assignment05_16.vo Assignment05_17.vo Assignment05_18.vo Assignment05_19.vo
Assignment05_20.vo Assignment05_21.vo Assignment05_22.vo Assignment05_23.vo Assi
gnment05_24.vo Assignment05_25.vo Assignment05_26.vo Assignment05_27.vo Assignme
nt05_28.vo Assignment05_29.vo Assignment05_30.vo Assignment05_31.vo Assignment05
_32.vo Assignment05_33.vo Assignment05_34.vo Assignment05_35.vo Assignment05_36.
vo Assignment05_37.vo Assignment05_38.vo Assignment05_39.vo Symbols.vi Preface.v
i Basics.vi Induction.vi Lists.vi Poly.vi MoreCoq.vi Logic.vi Prop.vi MoreLogic.
vi ProofObjects.vi MoreInd.vi SfLib.vi Rel.vi Imp.vi ImpParser.vi ImpCEvalFun.vi
 Extraction.vi Equiv.vi Hoare.vi Hoare2.vi HoareAsLogic.vi Smallstep.vi Auto.vi
Types.vi Stlc.vi StlcProp.vi MoreStlc.vi Sub.vi Typechecking.vi Records.vi Refer
ences.vi RecordSub.vi Norm.vi LibTactics.vi UseTactics.vi UseAuto.vi PE.vi Posts
cript.vi Assignment01.vi Assignment_02.vi Assignment03.vi Assignment04.vi Assign
ment05_00.vi Assignment05_01.vi Assignment05_02.vi Assignment05_03.vi Assignment
05_04.vi Assignment05_05.vi Assignment05_06.vi Assignment05_07.vi Assignment05_0
8.vi Assignment05_09.vi Assignment05_10.vi Assignment05_11.vi Assignment05_12.vi
 Assignment05_13.vi Assignment05_14.vi Assignment05_15.vi Assignment05_16.vi Ass
ignment05_17.vi Assignment05_18.vi Assignment05_19.vi Assignment05_20.vi Assignm
ent05_21.vi Assignment05_22.vi Assignment05_23.vi Assignment05_24.vi Assignment0
5_25.vi Assignment05_26.vi Assignment05_27.vi Assignment05_28.vi Assignment05_29
.vi Assignment05_30.vi Assignment05_31.vi Assignment05_32.vi Assignment05_33.vi
Assignment05_34.vi Assignment05_35.vi Assignment05_36.vi Assignment05_37.vi Assi
gnment05_38.vi Assignment05_39.vi Symbols.g Preface.g Basics.g Induction.g Lists
.g Poly.g MoreCoq.g Logic.g Prop.g MoreLogic.g ProofObjects.g MoreInd.g SfLib.g
Rel.g Imp.g ImpParser.g ImpCEvalFun.g Extraction.g Equiv.g Hoare.g Hoare2.g Hoar
eAsLogic.g Smallstep.g Auto.g Types.g Stlc.g StlcProp.g MoreStlc.g Sub.g Typeche
cking.g Records.g References.g RecordSub.g Norm.g LibTactics.g UseTactics.g UseA
uto.g PE.g Postscript.g Assignment01.g Assignment_02.g Assignment03.g Assignment
04.g Assignment05_00.g Assignment05_01.g Assignment05_02.g Assignment05_03.g Ass
ignment05_04.g Assignment05_05.g Assignment05_06.g Assignment05_07.g Assignment0
5_08.g Assignment05_09.g Assignment05_10.g Assignment05_11.g Assignment05_12.g A
ssignment05_13.g Assignment05_14.g Assignment05_15.g Assignment05_16.g Assignmen
t05_17.g Assignment05_18.g Assignment05_19.g Assignment05_20.g Assignment05_21.g
 Assignment05_22.g Assignment05_23.g Assignment05_24.g Assignment05_25.g Assignm
ent05_26.g Assignment05_27.g Assignment05_28.g Assignment05_29.g Assignment05_30
.g Assignment05_31.g Assignment05_32.g Assignment05_33.g Assignment05_34.g Assig
nment05_35.g Assignment05_36.g Assignment05_37.g Assignment05_38.g Assignment05_
39.g Symbols.v.d Preface.v.d Basics.v.d Induction.v.d Lists.v.d Poly.v.d MoreCoq
.v.d Logic.v.d Prop.v.d MoreLogic.v.d ProofObjects.v.d MoreInd.v.d SfLib.v.d Rel
.v.d Imp.v.d ImpParser.v.d ImpCEvalFun.v.d Extraction.v.d Equiv.v.d Hoare.v.d Ho
are2.v.d HoareAsLogic.v.d Smallstep.v.d Auto.v.d Types.v.d Stlc.v.d StlcProp.v.d
 MoreStlc.v.d Sub.v.d Typechecking.v.d Records.v.d References.v.d RecordSub.v.d
Norm.v.d LibTactics.v.d UseTactics.v.d UseAuto.v.d PE.v.d Postscript.v.d Assignm
ent01.v.d Assignment_02.v.d Assignment03.v.d Assignment04.v.d Assignment05_00.v.
d Assignment05_01.v.d Assignment05_02.v.d Assignment05_03.v.d Assignment05_04.v.
d Assignment05_05.v.d Assignment05_06.v.d Assignment05_07.v.d Assignment05_08.v.
d Assignment05_09.v.d Assignment05_10.v.d Assignment05_11.v.d Assignment05_12.v.
d Assignment05_13.v.d Assignment05_14.v.d Assignment05_15.v.d Assignment05_16.v.
d Assignment05_17.v.d Assignment05_18.v.d Assignment05_19.v.d Assignment05_20.v.
d Assignment05_21.v.d Assignment05_22.v.d Assignment05_23.v.d Assignment05_24.v.
d Assignment05_25.v.d Assignment05_26.v.d Assignment05_27.v.d Assignment05_28.v.
d Assignment05_29.v.d Assignment05_30.v.d Assignment05_31.v.d Assignment05_32.v.
d Assignment05_33.v.d Assignment05_34.v.d Assignment05_35.v.d Assignment05_36.v.
d Assignment05_37.v.d Assignment05_38.v.d Assignment05_39.v.d Symbols.v.beautifi
ed Preface.v.beautified Basics.v.beautified Induction.v.beautified Lists.v.beaut
ified Poly.v.beautified MoreCoq.v.beautified Logic.v.beautified Prop.v.beautifie
d MoreLogic.v.beautified ProofObjects.v.beautified MoreInd.v.beautified SfLib.v.
beautified Rel.v.beautified Imp.v.beautified ImpParser.v.beautified ImpCEvalFun.
v.beautified Extraction.v.beautified Equiv.v.beautified Hoare.v.beautified Hoare
2.v.beautified HoareAsLogic.v.beautified Smallstep.v.beautified Auto.v.beautifie
d Types.v.beautified Stlc.v.beautified StlcProp.v.beautified MoreStlc.v.beautifi
ed Sub.v.beautified Typechecking.v.beautified Records.v.beautified References.v.
beautified RecordSub.v.beautified Norm.v.beautified LibTactics.v.beautified UseT
actics.v.beautified UseAuto.v.beautified PE.v.beautified Postscript.v.beautified
 Assignment01.v.beautified Assignment_02.v.beautified Assignment03.v.beautified
Assignment04.v.beautified Assignment05_00.v.beautified Assignment05_01.v.beautif
ied Assignment05_02.v.beautified Assignment05_03.v.beautified Assignment05_04.v.
beautified Assignment05_05.v.beautified Assignment05_06.v.beautified Assignment0
5_07.v.beautified Assignment05_08.v.beautified Assignment05_09.v.beautified Assi
gnment05_10.v.beautified Assignment05_11.v.beautified Assignment05_12.v.beautifi
ed Assignment05_13.v.beautified Assignment05_14.v.beautified Assignment05_15.v.b
eautified Assignment05_16.v.beautified Assignment05_17.v.beautified Assignment05
_18.v.beautified Assignment05_19.v.beautified Assignment05_20.v.beautified Assig
nment05_21.v.beautified Assignment05_22.v.beautified Assignment05_23.v.beautifie
d Assignment05_24.v.beautified Assignment05_25.v.beautified Assignment05_26.v.be
autified Assignment05_27.v.beautified Assignment05_28.v.beautified Assignment05_
29.v.beautified Assignment05_30.v.beautified Assignment05_31.v.beautified Assign
ment05_32.v.beautified Assignment05_33.v.beautified Assignment05_34.v.beautified
 Assignment05_35.v.beautified Assignment05_36.v.beautified Assignment05_37.v.bea
utified Assignment05_38.v.beautified Assignment05_39.v.beautified Symbols.v.old
Preface.v.old Basics.v.old Induction.v.old Lists.v.old Poly.v.old MoreCoq.v.old
Logic.v.old Prop.v.old MoreLogic.v.old ProofObjects.v.old MoreInd.v.old SfLib.v.
old Rel.v.old Imp.v.old ImpParser.v.old ImpCEvalFun.v.old Extraction.v.old Equiv
.v.old Hoare.v.old Hoare2.v.old HoareAsLogic.v.old Smallstep.v.old Auto.v.old Ty
pes.v.old Stlc.v.old StlcProp.v.old MoreStlc.v.old Sub.v.old Typechecking.v.old
Records.v.old References.v.old RecordSub.v.old Norm.v.old LibTactics.v.old UseTa
ctics.v.old UseAuto.v.old PE.v.old Postscript.v.old Assignment01.v.old Assignmen
t_02.v.old Assignment03.v.old Assignment04.v.old Assignment05_00.v.old Assignmen
t05_01.v.old Assignment05_02.v.old Assignment05_03.v.old Assignment05_04.v.old A
ssignment05_05.v.old Assignment05_06.v.old Assignment05_07.v.old Assignment05_08
.v.old Assignment05_09.v.old Assignment05_10.v.old Assignment05_11.v.old Assignm
ent05_12.v.old Assignment05_13.v.old Assignment05_14.v.old Assignment05_15.v.old
 Assignment05_16.v.old Assignment05_17.v.old Assignment05_18.v.old Assignment05_
19.v.old Assignment05_20.v.old Assignment05_21.v.old Assignment05_22.v.old Assig
nment05_23.v.old Assignment05_24.v.old Assignment05_25.v.old Assignment05_26.v.o
ld Assignment05_27.v.old Assignment05_28.v.old Assignment05_29.v.old Assignment0
5_30.v.old Assignment05_31.v.old Assignment05_32.v.old Assignment05_33.v.old Ass
ignment05_34.v.old Assignment05_35.v.old Assignment05_36.v.old Assignment05_37.v
.old Assignment05_38.v.old Assignment05_39.v.old
process_begin: CreateProcess (NULL, rm -f Symbols.vo Preface.vo Basics.vo Inducti
on.vo Lists.vo Poly.vo MoreCoq.vo Logic.vo Prop.vo MoreLogic.vo ProofObjects.vo
MoreInd.vo SfLib.vo Rel.vo Imp.vo ImpParser.vo ImpCEvalFun.vo Extraction.vo Equi
v.vo Hoare.vo Hoare2.vo HoareAsLogic.vo Smallstep.vo Auto.vo Types.vo Stlc.vo St
lcProp.vo MoreStlc.vo Sub.vo Typechecking.vo Records.vo References.vo RecordSub.
vo Norm.vo LibTactics.vo UseTactics.vo UseAuto.vo PE.vo Postscript.vo Assignment
01.vo Assignment_02.vo Assignment03.vo Assignment04.vo Assignment05_00.vo Assign
ment05_01.vo Assignment05_02.vo Assignment05_03.vo Assignment05_04.vo Assignment
05_05.vo Assignment05_06.vo Assignment05_07.vo Assignment05_08.vo Assignment05_0
9.vo Assignment05_10.vo Assignment05_11.vo Assignment05_12.vo Assignment05_13.vo
 Assignment05_14.vo Assignment05_15.vo Assignment05_16.vo Assignment05_17.vo Ass
ignment05_18.vo Assignment05_19.vo Assignment05_20.vo Assignment05_21.vo Assignm
ent05_22.vo Assignment05_23.vo Assignment05_24.vo Assignment05_25.vo Assignment0
5_26.vo Assignment05_27.vo Assignment05_28.vo Assignment05_29.vo Assignment05_30
.vo Assignment05_31.vo Assignment05_32.vo Assignment05_33.vo Assignment05_34.vo
Assignment05_35.vo Assignment05_36.vo Assignment05_37.vo Assignment05_38.vo Assi
gnment05_39.vo Symbols.vi Preface.vi Basics.vi Induction.vi Lists.vi Poly.vi Mor
eCoq.vi Logic.vi Prop.vi MoreLogic.vi ProofObjects.vi MoreInd.vi SfLib.vi Rel.vi
 Imp.vi ImpParser.vi ImpCEvalFun.vi Extraction.vi Equiv.vi Hoare.vi Hoare2.vi Ho
areAsLogic.vi Smallstep.vi Auto.vi Types.vi Stlc.vi StlcProp.vi MoreStlc.vi Sub.
vi Typechecking.vi Records.vi References.vi RecordSub.vi Norm.vi LibTactics.vi U
seTactics.vi UseAuto.vi PE.vi Postscript.vi Assignment01.vi Assignment_02.vi Ass
ignment03.vi Assignment04.vi Assignment05_00.vi Assignment05_01.vi Assignment05_
02.vi Assignment05_03.vi Assignment05_04.vi Assignment05_05.vi Assignment05_06.v
i Assignment05_07.vi Assignment05_08.vi Assignment05_09.vi Assignment05_10.vi As
signment05_11.vi Assignment05_12.vi Assignment05_13.vi Assignment05_14.vi Assign
ment05_15.vi Assignment05_16.vi Assignment05_17.vi Assignment05_18.vi Assignment
05_19.vi Assignment05_20.vi Assignment05_21.vi Assignment05_22.vi Assignment05_2
3.vi Assignment05_24.vi Assignment05_25.vi Assignment05_26.vi Assignment05_27.vi
 Assignment05_28.vi Assignment05_29.vi Assignment05_30.vi Assignment05_31.vi Ass
ignment05_32.vi Assignment05_33.vi Assignment05_34.vi Assignment05_35.vi Assignm
ent05_36.vi Assignment05_37.vi Assignment05_38.vi Assignment05_39.vi Symbols.g P
reface.g Basics.g Induction.g Lists.g Poly.g MoreCoq.g Logic.g Prop.g MoreLogic.
g ProofObjects.g MoreInd.g SfLib.g Rel.g Imp.g ImpParser.g ImpCEvalFun.g Extract
ion.g Equiv.g Hoare.g Hoare2.g HoareAsLogic.g Smallstep.g Auto.g Types.g Stlc.g
StlcProp.g MoreStlc.g Sub.g Typechecking.g Records.g References.g RecordSub.g No
rm.g LibTactics.g UseTactics.g UseAuto.g PE.g Postscript.g Assignment01.g Assign
ment_02.g Assignment03.g Assignment04.g Assignment05_00.g Assignment05_01.g Assi
gnment05_02.g Assignment05_03.g Assignment05_04.g Assignment05_05.g Assignment05
_06.g Assignment05_07.g Assignment05_08.g Assignment05_09.g Assignment05_10.g As
signment05_11.g Assignment05_12.g Assignment05_13.g Assignment05_14.g Assignment
05_15.g Assignment05_16.g Assignment05_17.g Assignment05_18.g Assignment05_19.g
Assignment05_20.g Assignment05_21.g Assignment05_22.g Assignment05_23.g Assignme
nt05_24.g Assignment05_25.g Assignment05_26.g Assignment05_27.g Assignment05_28.
g Assignment05_29.g Assignment05_30.g Assignment05_31.g Assignment05_32.g Assign
ment05_33.g Assignment05_34.g Assignment05_35.g Assignment05_36.g Assignment05_3
7.g Assignment05_38.g Assignment05_39.g Symbols.v.d Preface.v.d Basics.v.d Induc
tion.v.d Lists.v.d Poly.v.d MoreCoq.v.d Logic.v.d Prop.v.d MoreLogic.v.d ProofOb
jects.v.d MoreInd.v.d SfLib.v.d Rel.v.d Imp.v.d ImpParser.v.d ImpCEvalFun.v.d Ex
traction.v.d Equiv.v.d Hoare.v.d Hoare2.v.d HoareAsLogic.v.d Smallstep.v.d Auto.
v.d Types.v.d Stlc.v.d StlcProp.v.d MoreStlc.v.d Sub.v.d Typechecking.v.d Record
s.v.d References.v.d RecordSub.v.d Norm.v.d LibTactics.v.d UseTactics.v.d UseAut
o.v.d PE.v.d Postscript.v.d Assignment01.v.d Assignment_02.v.d Assignment03.v.d
Assignment04.v.d Assignment05_00.v.d Assignment05_01.v.d Assignment05_02.v.d Ass
ignment05_03.v.d Assignment05_04.v.d Assignment05_05.v.d Assignment05_06.v.d Ass
ignment05_07.v.d Assignment05_08.v.d Assignment05_09.v.d Assignment05_10.v.d Ass
ignment05_11.v.d Assignment05_12.v.d Assignment05_13.v.d Assignment05_14.v.d Ass
ignment05_15.v.d Assignment05_16.v.d Assignment05_17.v.d Assignment05_18.v.d Ass
ignment05_19.v.d Assignment05_20.v.d Assignment05_21.v.d Assignment05_22.v.d Ass
ignment05_23.v.d Assignment05_24.v.d Assignment05_25.v.d Assignment05_26.v.d Ass
ignment05_27.v.d Assignment05_28.v.d Assignment05_29.v.d Assignment05_30.v.d Ass
ignment05_31.v.d Assignment05_32.v.d Assignment05_33.v.d Assignment05_34.v.d Ass
ignment05_35.v.d Assignment05_36.v.d Assignment05_37.v.d Assignment05_38.v.d Ass
ignment05_39.v.d Symbols.v.beautified Preface.v.beautified Basics.v.beautified I
nduction.v.beautified Lists.v.beautified Poly.v.beautified MoreCoq.v.beautified
Logic.v.beautified Prop.v.beautified MoreLogic.v.beautified ProofObjects.v.beaut
ified MoreInd.v.beautified SfLib.v.beautified Rel.v.beautified Imp.v.beautified
ImpParser.v.beautified ImpCEvalFun.v.beautified Extraction.v.beautified Equiv.v.
beautified Hoare.v.beautified Hoare2.v.beautified HoareAsLogic.v.beautified Smal
lstep.v.beautified Auto.v.beautified Types.v.beautified Stlc.v.beautified StlcPr
op.v.beautified MoreStlc.v.beautified Sub.v.beautified Typechecking.v.beautified
 Records.v.beautified References.v.beautified RecordSub.v.beautified Norm.v.beau
tified LibTactics.v.beautified UseTactics.v.beautified UseAuto.v.beautified PE.v
.beautified Postscript.v.beautified Assignment01.v.beautified Assignment_02.v.be
autified Assignment03.v.beautified Assignment04.v.beautified Assignment05_00.v.b
eautified Assignment05_01.v.beautified Assignment05_02.v.beautified Assignment05
_03.v.beautified Assignment05_04.v.beautified Assignment05_05.v.beautified Assig
nment05_06.v.beautified Assignment05_07.v.beautified Assignment05_08.v.beautifie
d Assignment05_09.v.beautified Assignment05_10.v.beautified Assignment05_11.v.be
autified Assignment05_12.v.beautified Assignment05_13.v.beautified Assignment05_
14.v.beautified Assignment05_15.v.beautified Assignment05_16.v.beautified Assign
ment05_17.v.beautified Assignment05_18.v.beautified Assignment05_19.v.beautified
 Assignment05_20.v.beautified Assignment05_21.v.beautified Assignment05_22.v.bea
utified Assignment05_23.v.beautified Assignment05_24.v.beautified Assignment05_2
5.v.beautified Assignment05_26.v.beautified Assignment05_27.v.beautified Assignm
ent05_28.v.beautified Assignment05_29.v.beautified Assignment05_30.v.beautified
Assignment05_31.v.beautified Assignment05_32.v.beautified Assignment05_33.v.beau
tified Assignment05_34.v.beautified Assignment05_35.v.beautified Assignment05_36
.v.beautified Assignment05_37.v.beautified Assignment05_38.v.beautified Assignme
nt05_39.v.beautified Symbols.v.old Preface.v.old Basics.v.old Induction.v.old Li
sts.v.old Poly.v.old MoreCoq.v.old Logic.v.old Prop.v.old MoreLogic.v.old ProofO
bjects.v.old MoreInd.v.old SfLib.v.old Rel.v.old Imp.v.old ImpParser.v.old ImpCE
valFun.v.old Extraction.v.old Equiv.v.old Hoare.v.old Hoare2.v.old HoareAsLogic.
v.old Smallstep.v.old Auto.v.old Types.v.old Stlc.v.old StlcProp.v.old MoreStlc.
v.old Sub.v.old Typechecking.v.old Records.v.old References.v.old RecordSub.v.ol
d Norm.v.old LibTactics.v.old UseTactics.v.old UseAuto.v.old PE.v.old Postscript
.v.old Assignment01.v.old Assignment_02.v.old Assignment03.v.old Assignment04.v.
old Assignment05_00.v.old Assignment05_01.v.old Assignment05_02.v.old Assignment
05_03.v.old Assignment05_04.v.old Assignment05_05.v.old Assignment05_06.v.old As
signment05_07.v.old Assignment05_08.v.old Assignment05_09.v.old Assignment05_10.
v.old Assignment05_11.v.old Assignment05_12.v.old Assignment05_13.v.old Assignme
nt05_14.v.old Assignment05_15.v.old Assignment05_16.v.old Assignment05_17.v.old
Assignment05_18.v.old Assignment05_19.v.old Assignment05_20.v.old Assignment05_2
1.v.old Assignment05_22.v.old Assignment05_23.v.old Assignment05_24.v.old Assign
ment05_25.v.old Assignment05_26.v.old Assignment05_27.v.old Assignment05_28.v.ol
d Assignment05_29.v.old Assignment05_30.v.old Assignment05_31.v.old Assignment05
_32.v.old Assignment05_33.v.old Assignment05_34.v.old Assignment05_35.v.old Assi
gnment05_36.v.old Assignment05_37.v.old Assignment05_38.v.old Assignment05_39.v.
old, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

```
#############################################################################
##  v      #                   The Coq Proof Assistant                     ##
## <O___,, #                INRIA - CNRS - LIX - LRI - PPS                 ##
##   \VV/  #                                                               ##
##    //   #  Makefile automagically generated by coq_makefile V8.4pl4     ##
#############################################################################

# WARNING
#
# This Makefile has been automagically generated
# Edit at your own risks !
#
# END OF WARNING

#
# This Makefile was generated by the command line :
# coq_makefile -install none Symbols.v Preface.v Basics.v Induction.v Lists.v Poly.v MoreCoq.v Logic.v Prop.v MoreLogic.v ProofObjects.v MoreInd.v SfLib.v Rel.v Imp.v ImpParser.v ImpCEvalFun.v Extraction.v Equiv.v Hoare.v Hoare2.v HoareAsLogic.v Smallstep.v Auto.v Types.v Stlc.v StlcProp.v MoreStlc.v Sub.v Typechecking.v Records.v References.v RecordSub.v Norm.v LibTactics.v UseTactics.v UseAuto.v PE.v Postscript.v -o Makefile 
#

.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

# 
# This Makefile may take arguments passed as environment variables:
# COQBIN to specify the directory where Coq binaries resides;
# ZDEBUG/COQDEBUG to specify debug flags for ocamlc&ocamlopt/coqc;
# DSTROOT to specify a prefix to install path.

# Here is a hack to make $(eval $(shell works:
define donewline


endef
includecmdwithout@ = $(eval $(subst @,$(donewline),$(shell { $(1) | tr -d '\r' | tr '\n' '@'; })))
$(call includecmdwithout@,$(COQBIN)coqtop -config)

##########################
#                        #
# Libraries definitions. #
#                        #
##########################

COQLIBS?=-I . 
COQDOCLIBS?=

##########################
#                        #
# Variables definitions. #
#                        #
##########################


OPT?=
COQDEP?=$(COQBIN)coqdep -c
COQFLAGS?=-q $(OPT) $(COQLIBS) $(OTHERFLAGS) $(COQ_XML)
COQCHKFLAGS?=-silent -o
COQDOCFLAGS?=-interpolate -utf8
COQC?=$(COQBIN)coqc
GALLINA?=$(COQBIN)gallina
COQDOC?=$(COQBIN)coqdoc
COQCHK?=$(COQBIN)coqchk

######################
#                    #
# Files dispatching. #
#                    #
######################

VFILES:=Symbols.v\
  Preface.v\
  Basics.v\
  Induction.v\
  Lists.v\
  Poly.v\
  MoreCoq.v\
  Logic.v\
  Prop.v\
  MoreLogic.v\
  ProofObjects.v\
  MoreInd.v\
  SfLib.v\
  Rel.v\
  Imp.v\
  ImpParser.v\
  ImpCEvalFun.v\
  Extraction.v\
  Equiv.v\
  Hoare.v\
  Hoare2.v\
  HoareAsLogic.v\
  Smallstep.v\
  Auto.v\
  Types.v\
  Stlc.v\
  StlcProp.v\
  MoreStlc.v\
  Sub.v\
  Typechecking.v\
  Records.v\
  References.v\
  RecordSub.v\
  Norm.v\
  LibTactics.v\
  UseTactics.v\
  UseAuto.v\
  PE.v\
  Postscript.v\
  Assignment01.v\
  Assignment_02.v\
  Assignment03.v\
  Assignment04.v\
  Assignment05_00.v\
  Assignment05_01.v\
  Assignment05_02.v\
  Assignment05_03.v\
  Assignment05_04.v\
  Assignment05_05.v\
  Assignment05_06.v\
  Assignment05_07.v\
  Assignment05_08.v\
  Assignment05_09.v\
  Assignment05_10.v\
  Assignment05_11.v\
  Assignment05_12.v\
  Assignment05_13.v\
  Assignment05_14.v\
  Assignment05_15.v\
  Assignment05_16.v\
  Assignment05_17.v\
  Assignment05_18.v\
  Assignment05_19.v\
  Assignment05_20.v\
  Assignment05_21.v\
  Assignment05_22.v\
  Assignment05_23.v\
  Assignment05_24.v\
  Assignment05_25.v\
  Assignment05_26.v\
  Assignment05_27.v\
  Assignment05_28.v\
  Assignment05_29.v\
  Assignment05_30.v\
  Assignment05_31.v\
  Assignment05_32.v\
  Assignment05_33.v\
  Assignment05_34.v\
  Assignment05_35.v\
  Assignment05_36.v\
  Assignment05_37.v\
  Assignment05_38.v\
  Assignment05_39.v

-include $(addsuffix .d,$(VFILES))
.SECONDARY: $(addsuffix .d,$(VFILES))

VOFILES:=$(VFILES:.v=.vo)
VOFILESINC=$(filter $(wildcard ./*),$(VOFILES)) 
GLOBFILES:=$(VFILES:.v=.glob)
VIFILES:=$(VFILES:.v=.vi)
GFILES:=$(VFILES:.v=.g)
HTMLFILES:=$(VFILES:.v=.html)
GHTMLFILES:=$(VFILES:.v=.g.html)
ifeq '$(HASNATDYNLINK)' 'true'
HASNATDYNLINK_OR_EMPTY := yes
else
HASNATDYNLINK_OR_EMPTY :=
endif

#######################################
#                                     #
# Definition of the toplevel targets. #
#                                     #
#######################################

all: $(VOFILES) 

spec: $(VIFILES)

gallina: $(GFILES)

html: $(GLOBFILES) $(VFILES)
    - mkdir -p html
    $(COQDOC) -toc $(COQDOCFLAGS) -html $(COQDOCLIBS) -d html $(VFILES)

gallinahtml: $(GLOBFILES) $(VFILES)
    - mkdir -p html
    $(COQDOC) -toc $(COQDOCFLAGS) -html -g $(COQDOCLIBS) -d html $(VFILES)

all.ps: $(VFILES)
    $(COQDOC) -toc $(COQDOCFLAGS) -ps $(COQDOCLIBS) -o $@ `$(COQDEP) -sort -suffix .v $^`

all-gal.ps: $(VFILES)
    $(COQDOC) -toc $(COQDOCFLAGS) -ps -g $(COQDOCLIBS) -o $@ `$(COQDEP) -sort -suffix .v $^`

all.pdf: $(VFILES)
    $(COQDOC) -toc $(COQDOCFLAGS) -pdf $(COQDOCLIBS) -o $@ `$(COQDEP) -sort -suffix .v $^`

all-gal.pdf: $(VFILES)
    $(COQDOC) -toc $(COQDOCFLAGS) -pdf -g $(COQDOCLIBS) -o $@ `$(COQDEP) -sort -suffix .v $^`

validate: $(VOFILES)
    $(COQCHK) $(COQCHKFLAGS) $(COQLIBS) $(notdir $(^:.vo=))

beautify: $(VFILES:=.beautified)
    for file in $^; do mv $${file%.beautified} $${file%beautified}old && mv $${file} $${file%.beautified}; done
    @echo 'Do not do "make clean" until you are sure that everything went well!'
    @echo 'If there were a problem, execute "for file in $$(find . -name \*.v.old -print); do mv $${file} $${file%.old}; done" in your shell/'

.PHONY: all opt byte archclean clean install userinstall depend html validate

####################
#                  #
# Special targets. #
#                  #
####################

byte:
    $(MAKE) all "OPT:=-byte"

opt:
    $(MAKE) all "OPT:=-opt"

clean:
    rm -f $(VOFILES) $(VIFILES) $(GFILES) $(VFILES:.v=.v.d) $(VFILES:=.beautified) $(VFILES:=.old)
    rm -f all.ps all-gal.ps all.pdf all-gal.pdf all.glob $(VFILES:.v=.glob) $(VFILES:.v=.tex) $(VFILES:.v=.g.tex) all-mli.tex
    - rm -rf html mlihtml

archclean:
    rm -f *.cmx *.o

printenv:
    @$(COQBIN)coqtop -config
    @echo CAMLC =   $(CAMLC)
    @echo CAMLOPTC =    $(CAMLOPTC)
    @echo PP =  $(PP)
    @echo COQFLAGS =    $(COQFLAGS)
    @echo COQLIBINSTALL =   $(COQLIBINSTALL)
    @echo COQDOCINSTALL =   $(COQDOCINSTALL)

###################
#                 #
# Implicit rules. #
#                 #
###################

%.vo %.glob: %.v
    $(COQC) $(COQDEBUG) $(COQFLAGS) $*

%.vi: %.v
    $(COQC) -i $(COQDEBUG) $(COQFLAGS) $*

%.g: %.v
    $(GALLINA) $<

%.tex: %.v
    $(COQDOC) $(COQDOCFLAGS) -latex $< -o $@

%.html: %.v %.glob
    $(COQDOC) $(COQDOCFLAGS) -html $< -o $@

%.g.tex: %.v
    $(COQDOC) $(COQDOCFLAGS) -latex -g $< -o $@

%.g.html: %.v %.glob
    $(COQDOC)$(COQDOCFLAGS)  -html -g $< -o $@

%.v.d: %.v
    $(COQDEP) -slash $(COQLIBS) "$<" > "$@" || ( RV=$$?; rm -f "$@"; exit $${RV} )

%.v.beautified:
    $(COQC) $(COQDEBUG) $(COQFLAGS) -beautify $*

# WARNING
#
# This Makefile has been automagically generated
# Edit at your own risks !
#
# END OF WARNING

include .depend
```

Comment: Could we at least see the clean section of the `makefile`?

Comment: Also the first line of the error message suggests that you may have syntax error in your `makefile`, or the call to it.

Comment: Use code formatting for terminal output not quote formatting. Quote formatting screws up newlines (which matter). Please fix your post.

Comment: @John, I've included the makefile. Would you mind having another look?

Comment: @EtanReisner Formatting is fixed, would you mind having another look?

Comment: That error is likely coming from the `includecmdwithout@ = $(eval $(subst @,$(donewline),$(shell { $(1) | tr -d '\r' | tr '\n' '@'; })))` which is not a line that can work from the Windows command prompt as that is `sh`/`bash` and not cmd/batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to use git bash to execute make, make clean commands after I re-installed git under Program Files (previously it was in Program Files(x86)). Apparently there's a bug that is caused by the parentheses in the $PATH variable.